# How to assign hot keys to live templates in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, live-templates

I need to assign hot keys to live templates in WebStorm.
It's not suitable to press Ctrl + Alt + T and select live template from the list, I need to press hot key combination. I need it for surround templates.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-67811](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67811) to be notified on any progress with this feature